# odoo 13 xlsx report TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I use xlsx report module but I don't know why this problem is happend.

```
  File "/mnt/extra-addons/report_xlsx/controllers/main.py", line 45, in report_routes
    ("Content-Disposition", content_disposition(report_name + ".xlsx")),
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str'*
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sHPZp3bG

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zZ8ZM5bi

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RM12a13i

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4A2v0uUG

Comment: Above link is all my code for xlsx export report.

Comment: double-check with 'report_name' you found the false instead of having the report name (string) so check that and add the condition before string concat.